# Syntax for Slim template's "role" attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

The slim documentation says you can add a role attribute by using the `@` character, but I am getting syntax compile errors in my browser when doing that.

Example from 
https://github.com/slim-template/slim

> We can use it in Slim code like this
>
> ```
>  .person@admin = person.name
> ```
>
> which renders to
>
> ```
>  <div class="person" role="admin">Daniel</div>
> ```

My Code:

```
#navbar.affixable.navbar.navbar-default@navigation
  =link_to "G Who Said That", root_path
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li =link_to "About", about_path
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Text line not indented deep enough. The first text line defines the necessary text indentation. Are you trying to nest a child tag in a tag containing text? Use | for the text block! c:/Sites/gwhosaidthat/app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.slim, Line 4, Column 4 li =link_to "About", about_path

Comment: The @ symbol seems to be interpreted as expecting something else, thus the next line is flagged as invalid

Comment: And the code you've posted is what you're using, or from the docs?

Comment: Thanks - the navbar line is causing the error?

Comment: I've isolated that the `@navigation` portion alone is what causes the error.

Comment: Have you tried it without so many classes etc? EG `#navbar@navigation` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a single class. Also I tried it with a single id. both give the same error.

Comment: @gwho This is a custom shortcut. Did you define it somewhere?

Comment: ah, I see. I don't see the documentation specifying where (in which file) to define the shortcut.

Comment: @gwho i'm also searching where to write it. Can you try it in application.rb ?

Comment: I am now getting a different error, after trying it in application.rb
It seems to be valid, and the entire partial seems to be OK. It raises an error at the next portion of the application.html file, even though that portion is valid syntax.
Unknown line indicator c:/Sites/gwhosaidthat/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim, Line 14, Column 6 .notice= notice ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom shortcut and you need to define it before using it. You can define it by:

```
Slim::Engine.set_default_options :shortcut => {'@' => {:attr => 'role'}, '#' => {:attr => 'id'}, '.' => {:attr => 'class'}}
```

Couldn't find documentation on where to define it, give it a try in application.rb and if it doesn't work then you can use normal approach

```
#navbar.affixable.navbar.navbar-default{role: "navigation"}
```

Comment: Ah, i might as well use the normal approach